# Calling Access Subroutine from Python

Tags: python, vba, ms-access

I am trying to run a sub in Access VBA from Python but it looks like I am facing an issue I do not quite manage to understand. Below the code that correctly opens the database (Access) but fail to run the VBA code

```
import os, os.path
import win32com.client

ac = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
ac.Visible=True
ac.OpenCurrentDatabase(os.path.abspath("C:\Database.accdb"))
ac.Application.Run("Database.accdb!module3.subpycall")
```

The sub I am calling is quite straight forward and it is calling a click event of a button. The code of the sub can be found below

```
Sub subpycall()
    Call cmdUniverse_Click
End Sub
```

When running python,as per the above code, Access opens correctly, the main forms opens correctly but it returns the following error. Can anyhone help fixing this error?

> File "C:\ON_CHAV.py", line 7, in 
> ac.Application.Run("Database.accdb!module3.subpycall")   File "<COMObject >", line 14, in Run   File
> "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py",
> line 287, in *ApplyTypes*
> result = self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args) pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567,
> 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, "Database cannot find the procedure
> 'Database.accdb!module3.subpycall.'", None, -1, -2146825771), None)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this via VBS before (not sure if this is an option for you), but it's simple and can be scheduled in the Win TaskScheduler.

```
Step1:
In your Access module1 (?), make your 'calling' proc 'public' and (not needed), qualify where the button on a form is:

Public Sub subpycall()
    Call Form_frmMain.cmdUniverse_Click
End Sub

Step2:
Create a VBS file and put this code in it.  Use the Access object to open your database, wait for it to load 60 secs, and then call the subpycall proc.  Save as eg, subpycall.vbs:

Dim accessApp
set accessApp = createObject("Access.Application") 
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("C:\CHAV.accdb")
accessApp.Visible = True
accessApp.DoCmd.OpenForm "FrmMain"
WScript.Sleep 60000
accessApp.Run "subpycall"
accessApp.Quit
Set accessApp = Nothing

Step3:
Create a bat file and put these lines in and save as subpycall.bat :

@echo off
cscript "C:\subpycall.vbs"

Step 4 (optional):
Schedule the subpycall.bat

Hope this helps.
```

Comment: Thanks @suki this is a nice workaround which works, but would love to call it from python as I already have a py code calling an xlsx vba code so has to be a way to call a VBA code in Access. In the meantime will test your solution and keep you posted. Thanks for the whole code!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how to solve your main question... but when I need to run VBA from python I create a VBS (VB script file) and call it from Python.

It may be an alternative to solve your problem, and will also release you from using msaccess.

Example Python calling:

```
  os.system('CSCRIPT my_script.vbs "' + os.getcwd() + '\\' + filename + '"')#filename is a paramenter I send to the scrit
```

Example VBS:

```
Dim filename, objWorkBook
'On Error Resume Next
filename = WScript.Arguments(0)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
temp_filename = Left(filename,InstrRev(filename,"\")) & "3A4Output.xlsb"
fso.CopyFile "my_file.xlsb", filename
'and so on...
```

Comment: Thanks @Fabrico this seems to be the same workaround proposed by Suki (below) which seems to work

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things to address here:

1. `Run` needs a function that's not scoped, thus `Database.accdb!module3.` is not needed
2. `Run` needs a *function* name, and `subpycall` is a sub
3. `subpycall` needs to be public, which is default, but imo should be specified nonetheless
4. `ac` is already the application, so no need to do `.Application`

Thus:

```py
ac.Run("subpycall")
```

and:

```vb
Public Function subpycall() 'Implicit As Variant
    Call cmdUniverse_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't seem to work



ac.Run("subpycall")
  File "<COMObject Access.Application>", line 14, in Run
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352562), None)